# Remove "public" on URL for subdirectory installation?

Tags: nginx, regex

This is Laravel installation. Laravel has separate `public` directory to set as root in Nginx. In my setup, I set `/var/www/web.dev/public` as root.

But I have many other individual installations in subdirectory which accessible from `http://web.dev/dev/1/public/`, `http://web.dev/dev/2/public/` and so on.

The `public` directory of individual installations located in `/var/www/web.dev/public/dev/1/public`, `/var/www/web.dev/public/dev/2/public`, and so on.

I want to remove the `public` to make it accessible from `http://web.dev/dev/1/`, `http://web.dev/dev/2/`, and so on.

Below what I've done so far (using regex to remove `public` in URL):

```
server {
    server_name web.dev;
    root   /var/www/web.dev/public;
    index  index.php;
    location / {
        rewrite ^\/([^\/]*)\/([^\/]*)\/([^\/]*)$ /public/$3 break;
    }
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    location ~ \.php$ {
        include         fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_pass    unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    }
}
```

I've tried several other regex, and still no luck:

```
    location ^\/(.*)\/public {
        rewrite ^(.*)$ /public/$2 break;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Placing the `rewrite...break` within the `location /` block means that `.php` URIs will not be rewritten.

The simplest fix will be to move the `rewrite...break` into the `server` block and use `last` instead.

```
rewrite ^(/dev/[^/]+)((?!/public)/.*)?$ $1/public$2 last;

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
}
location ~ \.php$ {
    ...
}
```

The regular expression has a negative look-ahead assertion to prevent multiple additions of `/public`. One limitation with this approach is that the default controller is also going to be the main website (as defined by the `try_files` statement).

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite) for more.

---

My preferred solution would be to separate the configuration for the development sites and use `alias` to construct the path to files. One advantage being that the files no longer need to be inside the main website.

```
location ~ ^(?<prefix>/dev/[^/]+)(?<suffix>/.*)?$ {
    alias /usr/local/www/test$prefix/public$suffix;

    if (!-e $request_filename) { rewrite ^(/dev/[^/]+) $1/index.php last; }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        if (!-f $request_filename) { return 404; }

        include         fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
        fastcgi_pass    unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    }
}
```

Place this block **above** other regular expression location blocks, as regular expressions are evaluated in order. Notice the use of `$request_filename` for the value of `SCRIPT_FILENAME`.

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#alias) for more. Avoid using `try_files` with `alias` due to [this issue](https://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/97) and note [this caution](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/) on the use of `if`.

Comment: The regex looks right. Second match is `/public`. But strangely not works. `http://web.dev/dev/2/` giving 404 code while `http://web.dev/dev/2` redirected to `http://web.dev/dev/2/public/` and it showing main site contents.

Comment: I have updated the regex to fix one side-effect, but I have also added a better solution which will (hopefully) work with Laravel.